# How to get the username when they login and store it to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the username when users login, after that, when they want do vote for a particular candidate, they click the vote button, then the users's username will be store in the database. Any suggestion on how to do it? For the display of the candidate details(for voting), i use the gridview, now, I able to store the candidate details in the database, just left the username of the voter.

```
protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String MyConnection2 = "Server=localhost;database=ovs;Uid=root;password=; Convert Zero Datetime=True";
     
        MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2);      
        GridViewRow grdrow = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;
        Label lblStudentId = (Label)grdrow.Cells[0].FindControl("lblID");
        string studentId = lblStudentId.Text;
        String query = "insert into voting (studentID,)values ('" + lblStudentId.Text + "')";  
        MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(query, MyConn2);
        MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
        MyConn2.Open();
        MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();

        while (MyReader2.Read())
        {
        }
        MyConn2.Close();
    }

    }
```

When the users click the vote button, the candidateID that being displayed in the gridview will be store to the database.However, I want to store who vote for the particular candidate (store they studentID). I'd like capture thier username when they login, and when they click the vote button, insert their studentID to the database

```
 Session["UserName"] = txtID.Text;
txtID.Text = Session["UserName"].ToString();
```

I store the session in the user login page. How can I store it to the database using the insert command(when they click the vote button)?

Comment: please put a bit more effort in the question. At least show us some code.

Comment: Holy SQL injection, Batman.

Comment: Are you mean using SQL ?

Comment: I'd like to insert the session Session["UserName"] that I stored into the database when the users clicked vote button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Viewstate` or `Session` object to store the username. Then retrieve the username from that.
`Set` value to `session` or `viewstate`

```
Session["Username"]=txtusername.Text;
Viewstate["Username"]=txtusername.Text;
```

`get` value from `session` or `viewstate`

```
Response.Write(Session["Username"].ToString());
Response.Write(Session["Username"].ToString());
```

Comment: Which mean I store the session in the user login page, get it at another page?. How can I store it in database by using the insert command?

Comment: @ycwong Yes. You can set the session in login page, then retrieve login information from session. Insert command as follows
`Insert into table values('"+Session["Username"].ToString()+"')`